# custom css for common w3.css classes

Tags: html, css

I have been looking at the W3.CSS framework and at first sight looks interesting, BUT adding all the 'css' into the HTML seems to defeat the purpose of css. Take this for example (three rows with different widths but identical colours and justification):

m4

m6

m2

```
<div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-red w3-center w3-container"><p>m4</p></div>
    <div class="w3-col m6 w3-light-grey w3-center"><p>m6</p></div>
    <div class="w3-col m2 w3-light-grey w3-center"><p>m2</p></div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-red w3-center w3-container"><p>m4</p></div>
    <div class="w3-col m6 w3-light-grey w3-center"><p>m6</p></div>
    <div class="w3-col m2 w3-light-grey w3-center"><p>m2</p></div>
</div>
```

That's a lot of repetition and a nightmare to change afterward. Is there a way to move the w3 classes into a custom css or use a mechanism like a C header file to collect all common attributes?

Comment: w3schools is not a particularly good web reference, and W3.CSS is a particularly bad CSS framework.

Comment: I have read that comment before, but in Google searches they pop up all over the place, so there must be some merit in it?

Comment: It's an old site that many people have linked to and referenced. Do not confuse popularity with quality.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the w3 css create your own css classes like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .row{
                height:20px;
                color:black;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row" style="width:80px">
            <p>Row 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="width:60px">
            <p>Row 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="width:40px">
            <p>Row 3</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you are trying to create a table because it seems like you might be wanting to use the files attached.
Have a look here [Link to Help Documents](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html/modules/learn-html-tables/cheatsheet)